# jmeter JSON Path Assertion how can i get value “1358”

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can I get value “1358”

[image]]

I tried:
[image]

But I get as response

```
Assertion failure message: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: THROW_ON_MISSING_PROPERTY
```

Comment: Try $.InstallCount.[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JSON Path to be `$..InstallCount[0]`, see [JSON Path Expressions](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) article for the language reference.

Also it would be better to move your JSON Path Assertion to be a child of the HTTP Request, otherwise it will be applied to all the samplers living at the same level and you'll be getting false negative results.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for detailed instructions on using assertions in your JMeter test script.